# Connection over a proxy Quickfix/j

Tags: proxy, connection, mina, quickfixj

I am trying to establish a connection with quickfix/j but i am behind the company firewall. So i need to connect over a proxy to the acceptor. I saw on the internet that with the new version 1.6.0 , proxy support was added but I couldn't find any explanations on how to do that. Can someone please explain how i can use the proxy from an initiator to establish a connection to the server (acceptor)?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code snippet you tried to use. It would help people answering your question greatly! Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Its not a recent question but i wanted to leave my solution here.

I replaced mina lib with mina-core-2.0.16.jar and i added proxy info to my settings file.

ProxyType=socks

ProxyVersion=5

ProxyHost=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

ProxyPort=1080

I connected successfully.

Comment: Does this work even if ProxyHost is a DNS and not IP?

Comment: can you please tell where exactly did you add these properties in initiator settings (in Session or Default). I am still facing issues while connecting to proxy.

Comment: i wrote my settings file below
[default]
ConnectionType=initiator
BeginString=FIX.4.4
LogonTimeout=30
ReconnectInterval=5
FileStorePath=fixlgs/str
FileLogPath=fixlgs/
FileLogHeartbeats=Y
SenderCompID=XXX
TargetCompID=XXX
RefreshOnLogon=Y
SocketUseSSL=Y
SocketKeyStore=xxx
SocketKeyStorePassword=XXX
ProxyType=socks
ProxyVersion=5
ProxyHost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ProxyPort=xxxx
EnabledProtocols= TLSv1.2
[session]
StartTime=17:05:00
EndTime=17:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
CheckLatency=Y
SocketConnectPort=xxxxx
SocketConnectHost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
UseDataDictionary=N
ResetSeqNumFlag=Y